# How exactly is the cancellation token mechanism implemented over HTTP?

Tags: web-development, web-api, front-end, backend, tokens

In a web application with a frontend and a backend part, how exactly is the cancellation token mechanism implemented over HTTP? HTTP is a stateless protocol and it does not allow "sharing" any data between the parties. So, how can the frontend create objects which then somehow "monitored" by the backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual cancellation token in ASP isn't transmitted at all, rather it comes from *loss of transmission*. If the connection between client and webserver is dropped while user code is generating content, the webserver may set the cancellation token to indicate "actually, don't bother, the result will be thrown away".

Comment: I thought HTTP connections closed after every request/response. So I guess, the cancellation data can be transferred while the connection is still open, before the response arrives back to the frontend? How is it transferred from frontend to backend? As a new HTTP request? Is there some documentation explaining this?

Comment: @Val the frontend closes the connection, which the backend can see

Comment: OK, I understood from this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection that the closing is done by the frontend (client) sending a message which, instead of containing a request, contains the close command for the server.

Comment: This would be easier to explain if you provided a concrete example of which cancellation token you mean, but: a HTTP connection can be closed AFTER the request but BEFORE the response. It's always possible to have an "unclean" close.

Comment: In my specific case, I'm using Blazor WASM and a .NET Web API for the backend. But I know cancellation tokens should work in any modern web framework so I figured this question is more related to the HTTP protocol.

Comment: No, I mean really specific like a code sample. Precise details of cancellation vary depending on language.

Answer (score 3):

Both sides have persistent storage, so we don't need the transport mechanism to have persistent storage. At a very naive level:

- Frontend to backend: "Please start doing THING for me"
- Backend to backend: "Sure, please use ID `0d6b739b-9a8d-404d-92cb-48bfb83ced1e` to refer to THING"
- ... time passes ...
- Frontend to backend: "Please stop what you were doing with ID `0d6b739b-9a8d-404d-92cb-48bfb83ced1e`"

Note that the transport mechanism isn't even mentioned here, we don't care if it's HTTP or small gnomes on bicycles.

Comment: And here I was thinking that HTTP *was* small gnomes on bicycles

Comment: @Caleth well, given [IP can be implemented by carrier pigeon](https://blug.linux.no/rfc1149/) so there's nothing stopping you doing HTTP that way.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is implemented on top of TCP. This means that at *any* point, the client can simply send a FIN packet to the server to close the connection. The server should react to this by indicating request cancellation.

Comment: Yes, the previous answeres helped me understand this. I'm still not sure about one more thing though - does this also work for HTTP non-persistent connections? Or only persistent connections are used nowadays in web apps?

Comment: Even a non-persistent connection is established and needs to remain open until the response has been received. The client can still close it at any point.

Comment: OK, I had selected the correct answer before but I gave you an upvote. Surprisingly, my question got a downvote for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of HTTP requests, cancellation tokens are implemented using the  interface in modern web APIs, particularly in JavaScript. It allows you to create an  instance and associate it with a fetch request. Then, you can use the associated  to signal cancellation, which can be observed by the fetch request, allowing it to abort the ongoing HTTP request.